# New posts with custom fields separated from normal posts?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on a WordPress website where they have generic posts every day.

At this moment, they asked me to separate normal post writing they do and to create a separated section on a dashboard that will work as normal post editing does but with some extra fields that are visible only on that post editors...

How do I do this? I have been searching for a few hours now I can't find anything about this.

EDIT: imgur.com/a/DSyt3

On the image on dashboard "Objave" is Croatian for Posts. As you can see, services are same as post editing, but is separated from posts, it does not list anything I write in posts, only things I write in services. I need to do that.

I need to create same thing as what posts do in wordpress, but it needs to stand on its own away from usual post editor, that means it lists only things i write in that new editor, and it can have aditional elements from ACF.

Comment: Hey, DO you want to add some extra fields for specific post type?

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Im trying to do this : https://imgur.com/a/DSyt3

This is a screenshot of a bought theme i used for one of my works, the theme had built in posts editor called services that worked just like normal post editors.

Comment: Okay, I have gone through this image. it seems, your site is in multi-language, where you can add different contents for each language.

Comment: so what do you want to do?

Comment: Ok i have no idea how to explain this... On the image on dashboard "Objave" is Croatian for Posts. As you can see, services are same as post editing, but is separated from posts, it does not list anything I write in posts, only things I write in services. I need to do that.

Comment: `it does not list anything` means do you want to display in frontend?

Comment: when you enter to dashboard > posts in it will list all of your posts.
When i enter dashboard > new editor( the one i need to create ) it should not list anything that was written in dashboard > posts 

Basically separate editors.

Comment: new editor or new service page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is to create **Custom Post Types**. There are plenty of plugins that will do that for you (https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/custom+post+type/) or you can create your own if you are happy writing code: https://codex.wordpress.org/custom_post_type

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes ! thank you. Im still new to this but this is it. Thank you so much. Thanks all for trying to help and sorry for my bad explaining